# why we used ajax. BeginForm in mvc instead adding form tags and Html.BeginForm

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

What is the use of Ajax.BeginForm in MVC4. Why do we use it, when we can just add a form tag directly, does this html helper add some capability or does something which cannot be done with a simple form tag. And also I have found something we can use Html.BeginForm for same purpose, So what is differences  between them

Comment: @StephenMuecke- necessary attributes  What does it means?I think we can use form tags for the same purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(1)Html.BeginForm will always use RouteTable to detrmine the action attribute value.
(2) provide client side validation
[http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/asp-net-mvc-client-side-validation-with-dynamic-contents]
```

Comment: `Html.BeginForm()` has got nothing to do with client side validation (other than adding the `novalidate` attribute)

Comment: @StephenMuecke It was required for MVC 3 and older, but OP quoted outdated information.

Answer (score 2):

""BeginForm()" is an extension method that writes an opening "" tag to the response. "BeginForm()" is an extension method for both HtmlHelper and AjaxHelper classes. It returns an MVCForm object from both HtmlHelper and AjaxHelper class instances so there is not much difference but the AjaxHelper method submits the form asynchronously using JavaScript."

You can also refer to the article for more details:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/working-with-html-beginform-and-ajax-beginform-in-mvc-3/